# How to concatenate the results obtained in a loop using R

Tags: r, function, loops

```
myFunction <- function(x){
for(i in 0:23)
{
if(i<10){
  timer <- paste("T0",i, sep ="")
  tempr <- grepl(timer,x)
  tempr <- table(tempr)["TRUE"]
  timeCount <- c(timer,tempr) 
}
else{
  timer <- paste("T",i,sep="")
  tempr <- grepl(timer,x)
  tempr <- table(tempr)["TRUE"]
  timeCount <- c(timer,tempr) 
}
}
return(timeCount)
}
tmp <- myFunction(test$timestamp)
```

What I am trying to do is in the function I am looping for 23 times and generating two values `timer` (contains values like T00, T01, T02...T23) and `tempr` (contains values like 23, 24, 25...). Now I want to store all the 23 respective values for the two variables in a dataframe so that my final output is

```
TimeZ Freq 
 T00   33
 T01   12
 T02   22
 T04   34
  .     .
  .     .
  .     .
 T23    23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several lessons to be learned here. You can use `seq(0,23)` to construct the initial sequence, make a 1-row dataframe for each value, and use `do.call` with `rbind` to join them. You don't need `paste` or the `if` because you can use `sprintf` to add the 0's as needed. Finally, you don't need to use `table` on your `grepl` because `which` does the same thing and is more succinct.

```
myFunction <- function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(0, 23), function(i)
  data.frame(TimeZ = timer <- sprintf("T%02d", i),
             Freq = which(grepl(timer, x))[1])
))

# example:
myFunction(sprintf("T%02d", sample(seq(0,23))))

#   TimeZ Freq
# 1   T00   14
# 2   T01   24
# 3   T02    2
# 4   T03    7
# 5   T04   19
# ----
#    TimeZ Freq
# 20   T19    9
# 21   T20   21
# 22   T21   22
# 23   T22   15
# 24   T23   13
```

If we are allowed to assume that `x` contains `T00`, `T01`, ..., `T23` (every single one of them), then it becomes even shorter:

```
 myFunction <- function(x) data.frame(TimeZ = sprintf("T%02d", seq(0, 23)),
                                      Freq = order(x))
```

Comment: X will be a value like "2008-08-13T23:04:10Z".... So I was using grepl to see if T00, T01...is present or not...

Comment: Your code is efficient and working but I have to make some minor changes before getting the desired result.. I have to write "Freq = table((grepl(timer, x)))["TRUE"]" in place of "Freq = which(grepl(timer, x))[1]"